# Phone Gap Build - Your ios platform does not have Api.js

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am getting the following error on PhoneGap Build:

```
Your ios platform does not have Api.js
```

Here's my config.xml:

http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"

```
<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->


<name>NAME</name>

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />

<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />


<description>
description
</description>


<author href="http://company.io" email="contact@company.io">
    Company, LLC
</author>

<access origin="http://example.com" subdomains="true" />

<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git" source="git" />
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>


<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="1.2.0" source="npm" />
<!--<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.5.0" source="pgb" />-->
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push.git#1.5.0">
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="chat-app-143622" />
    <param name="GOOGLE_APP_ID" value="1:763640140170:ios:2c80165fdf57078b"/>
</plugin>


<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>


<plugin name="https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin" source="git" version="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="933416606757546" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="NAME" />
</plugin>
```

I've been reading and even posted on the Apache Phone Gap Build forums but no luck. This error is new - it didn't happen in my previous builds over the past few years, even with the same app.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue with Adobe PGB on iOS with my project settings:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
    ...
</platform>
```

If you can update your CLI version without impacting other plugins, I resolved my build errors by going to cli-6.4.0:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.4.0" />
    ...
</platform>
```

You might choose a different version, but you can check which Cordova release it corresponds to here: https://build.phonegap.com/current-support

There is also a growing thread on the issue on their official forum:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/9727763#9727763